# File Rename not working

Tags: c#, string, file-io

```
FileInfo _fileinfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\Projects\LSImage\" + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString());         
File.Move(_fileinfo.FullName, _fileinfo.FullName.ToString().Replace(_fileinfo.FullName, dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString()));
```

It's throwing an error

> *Cannot create a file when that file already exists.*

I have to rename images in LsImages with applicationId from database, so i am prefixing with it application and and then applicationimage name from database

Comment: `_fileinfo.FullName` is already a string you don't need to cast it. Also your replace is removing the entire file path and name so why don't you just use: `File.Move(_fileinfo.FullName, dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString());`

Comment: @Prix , I dont think thats causing error

Comment: Error message isn't clear?

Comment: some where its suggesting to change to destination location, but i have to do in that location only

Comment: _fileinfo.FullName.ToString().Replace(_fileinfo.FullName,... that does not make much sense, you are replacing the full string

Comment: @user2553774 no that is not the error, what I pointed out was just unnecessary code. For example: `_fileinfo.FullName.ToString()` since `_fileinfo.FullName` is already a string you don't need to use `.ToString()`, and on your replace you are replacing your entire file name so if your database data is empty it will result on an empty filename.

Comment: @Prix i tried that, but same error

Comment: @SonerGönül , i am getting that error only

Comment: @user2553774 what does `MessageBox.Show("\"" + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + "\"-\"" + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString() + "\"");` tells you ? Or `Console.WriteLine` if its a console app.

Comment: values are there in dt.rows, problem is its not renaming the file in the same directory,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the full string:

File.Move(_fileinfo.FullName, **_fileinfo.FullName**.ToString().Replace(**_fileinfo.FullName**, dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString()));

Are you sure you dont want this instead?:

```
File.Move(_fileinfo.FullName, _fileinfo.FullName.ToString().Replace(dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"], dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString()));
```

Or:

```
File.Move(_fileinfo.FullName, _fileinfo.FullName.Replace(_fileinfo.Name, dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var defaultPath=@"D:\Projects\LSImage";
var appImage=dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString();
var appId=dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString();
var srcFile=Path.Combine(defaultPath,appImage);
var dstFile=Path.Combine(defaultPath,appId + appImage);
FileInfo _fileinfo = new FileInfo(srcFile);  // This isn't needed to rename
File.Move(srcFile,dstFile);
```

Comment: I combined the best ideas from below, mercilessly stolen ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
FileInfo _fileinfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\Projects\LSImage\" + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString());
try
{
    File.Move(_fileinfo.FullName, _fileinfo.FullName.ToString().Replace(_fileinfo.FullName, dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString()));
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    throw new Exception(String.Format("Trying to rename {0} to {1} failed!",_fileinfo.Fullname,dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString() + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString()));
}
```

Then tell us what it reports.

Comment: Trying to rename D:\Projects\LSImage\634696369076237653.png to 1634696369076237653.png failed!

Comment: @user2553774 change `.Replace(_fileinfo.FullName` to `.Replace(_fileinfo.Name`

Comment: Could be that 1634696369076237653.png exists in the programs current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to prepend the ApplicationID onto the front of the file. If so, try this:

```
FileInfo _fileinfo = new FileInfo(@"D:\Projects\LSImage\" + dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString());         

string appID = dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationID"].ToString();
string appImage = dt.Rows[0]["ApplicationImage"].ToString();
string newFullPath = @"D:\Projects\LSImage\" + appImage + appID;

File.Move(_fileinfo.FullName, newFullPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.Move(_fileinfo.FullNmae,_fileinfo.FullName.Replace(_FileInfo.Name,dt.rows[0]["apid"].tostring() + dr.rows[0]["apname"].tosring()))
```

Comment: @Prix Only from the source string, the replacement uses Name

Comment: @Prix , Actually i have solved this by my own, when i cam here to give answer, i saw this answer, similar to my own, so i marked it as best answer, later, i saw you have given similar answer couple of minutes before :-(

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as best answer, as you deserve :)

Comment: @Prix i dont bother with such kind of things,becuase usually i give answer by typing in notepad, so usually i do such kind of mistake, i only look for the things that i need

Comment: and sorry again, i marked fcuesta as a best answer , because he was the first gave such answer, i was thinking to mark my answer as best answer, but while in testing my code i got late. :-(